# Проблема с моей 2d псевдо-камерой (MonoGame)

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, monogame

Я только - только начинаю изучать MonoGame. Ради обучения, решил пока написать простую игрушку с изменяемым игровым миром (что - то вроде Terraria). 
Так вот, есть у меня двумерный массив мира(`int[1000,1000]`). Камера берёт какой - то небольшой кусок из этого массива и "кладёт" его в массив тех блоков, которые нужно нарисовать (`int[140,140]`). При движении камеры, чтобы возникала иллюзия движения, все блоки рисуются с небольшим отступом относительно позиции игрока. Вот код рисования блока

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(((i - 10) * 10) + fractionalpartXint, ((j - 10) * 10) + fractionalpartYint, 10, 10), Color.White);
```

К позиции по x и y прибавляются ещё две переменные: `fractionalpartXint` и `fractionalpartYint` соответственно. Эти две переменных - это просто первое число после запятой позиции игрока. Например, у игрока такие координаты: (`10.3 ; 4,5`) - это значит, что отступ по x - 3, по y - 5.

Проблема заключается в том, что если координаты камеры меньше 100, то все движения блоков плавные, всё хорошо, но если же больше 100, то их движения становятся дёрганными, резкими. При движении вбок, блоки движутся то вправо, то влево. Причём при отдалении от этого рубежа 100, характер движения блоков не изменяется. Ещё, для понятности. Изменил начальную позицию камеры на (500;10). Движение по x - дёрганное, по y - плавное. Стоит переместится на координаты (500;120), как и по y тоже начинаются такие лаги.

У кого какие идеи на этот счёт?

Comment: А как вы считаете fractionalpart...? Может, проблема в них?

Comment: Я перевожу позицию в string и с помощью цикла достаю оттуда первый символ после запятой, дальше приравниваю "fractionalpart..." к int.Parse(*здесь тот самый символ*);

Comment: Можете привести сам код. А зачем вы вообще их добавляете? Просто же сдвигает весь массив на непонятное число

Comment: А лучше всего вообще скинуть весь цикл отрисовки.